# App using Electron + discord-rpc gives error: "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, discord-rpc

I'm running a React JS electron app with `discord-rpc` to set a presence. I copied the discord example code and put it into the top of a `create-react-app` I started it and it gives me this error:

```
./node_modules/discord-rpc/src/client.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (644:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     return this.request(RPCCommands.GET_RELATIONSHIPS)
|       .then((o) => o.relationships.map((r) => ({
|         ...r,
|         type: types[r.type],
|       })));
```

I don't know what's going on. I tried looking it up, but I couldn't find anything. Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DiscordRPC } from 'discord-rpc'

const clientId = '821348434870403102';
const rpc = new DiscordRPC.Client({ transport: 'ipc' });

async function setActivity() {
  rpc.setActivity({
    details: 'Test Details',
    state: 'Teat State',
    instance: false,
  });
}

rpc.on('ready', () => {
  setActivity();
  setInterval(() => {
    setActivity();
  }, 15000);
});

rpc.login({ clientId }).catch(console.error);
```

Any help would be accepted!